# Postfix local mail delivery rate

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I would like to increase the speed of the delivery rate of postfix to the local mailboxes.

On the postfix man page I have found Resource And Rate Controls and I am trying to play with that.
Altough there is still 70 mails in the mailq all coming from outside (another mail server) into local mailboxes.

I have added:

```
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
local_destination_recipient_limit = 5
```

Here is my main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix



default_process_limit = 10

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /work/ssl/cert.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /work/ssl/cert.key


smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = my.mailserver.hu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = my.mailserver.hu, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_policy_greylist.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 4
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 4
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
#content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
#receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
   check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045

local_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
local_destination_recipient_limit = 5

command_time_limit = 60s

smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 35

smtputf8_enable = yes
```

My master.cf

```
smtp    inet  n     -   -   -   -   smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin

submission inet n - - - - smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject



smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject


pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache


maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}

#spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe
#  user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

spamass-dovecot unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u debian-spamd -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}

amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
        -o smtp_bind_address=
```

My amavis, I have commented out the calm-scan

```
#@bypass_virus_checks_maps = (
#   \%bypass_virus_checks, \@bypass_virus_checks_acl, \$bypass_virus_checks_re);

@bypass_spam_checks_maps = (
   \%bypass_spam_checks, \@bypass_spam_checks_acl, \$bypass_spam_checks_re);

1;
```

My postfwd.cf:

```
id=RULEZEROSASL
  sasl_username=~/^(\S+)$/
  action=rcpt(sasl_username/40/300/REJECT only 40 recipients per 5 minute for $$sasl_username)
```

Do you have any advice to increase the rate futher more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after 2 days of examining this issue I found the solution. g_bor was right, the problem causer was not the postfix, it was the amavis. It handled the mails slowly.

Important notice: my server has 8 cores.

My solution for the problem was to increase the amavis parallel processes number in two configs:
I added to the:

/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user file:
`$max_servers = 4;` (it makes 4 core to work nearly 100%)

And in the postfix master.cf I have modified this:

```
amavis unix - - - - 4 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
                -o smtp_bind_address=
```

As you see the last part is 4, the same as the $max_servers value.

Now the server load has increased, but it is still okay, and the mailq is emapty, the emails comes and goes fast.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that something might be delaying delivery. The most probable candidate is the policy service.

One easy way to check for that is to temporarily disable the graylisting, and maybe smtpd_data_restrictions. Is this possible in you situation?

Could you also show you master.cf? I would write this as a comment, but I lack the rep.

Comment: Thank You!  I have tried to turn off:
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
   check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045  but it did not helped. I have copied my main configs into the question

Comment: From the config I assume you are using postgrey to do the graylisting. You could try to set the delay option for postgrey in its config file, like described here: https://www.howtoforge.com/greylisting_postfix_postgrey . Does that help?